# Will I be able to wear 8 rings as an octopode after dragon form and necromutation?

Tags: dungeon-crawl-stone-soup

What happens to octopodes when they transmutate? Will their rings meld into their body?

The wiki article on dragon form says this:

> All equipment except for rings and amulets meld into your body

So does that mean I will be able to keep my 8 rings on?

What about necromutation?

Comment: The title of this question is like surrealist poetry on the front page.

Comment: Agreed.  This is the most awesome question title ever to grace gaming.

Comment: Crawl, now that is a real game :D.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The other posted answers were probably correct in 2012, but in modern versions of crawl, octopodes get 8 rings in all forms. You can be a dragon with 8 rings now.

Comment: I asked a dev and he confirms your answer. It was changed in version 0.16. Also, hi amalloy.

Answer (score 9):

As you would expect, you lose the extra rings when you transmute into a form that does not have 8 arms.  That means the first two rings you have will remain equipped, but the other six will be unequipped.

According to [the source code](http://gitorious.org/crawl/crawl/blobs/master/crawl-ref/source/transform.cc), Octopodes keep all eight rings only when they transmute into a spider (*quelle surprise*!).

Comment: Great answer! For clarification, the lich only has 2 ring slots? (it's a human-like lich?)

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  Liches are kind of "whatever you are"-like, in that you can continue to wear the armour and wield the weapons (except for holy weapons) you had prior to the transmutation. (I guess with the exception of the 8 tentacles vs two arms thing...)

Answer (score 7):

The source code shows that any form that keeps mutations will allow all eight rings as well.  Spider is a special case as it does not keep mutations but allows 8 rings.

The non mutation forms are lich, blade hands, statue form and beastly appendage as seen in the below code snippet constants.  A separate piece of code takes each piece of equipment off depending on whether its a ring at ring locations 3-8 and whether it meets keep-mutation or spider form in which case it declines to remove the ring.

Reference:

```
bool form_keeps_mutations(transformation_type form)
{
    switch (form)
    {
    case TRAN_NONE:
    case TRAN_BLADE_HANDS:
    case TRAN_STATUE:
    case TRAN_LICH:
    case TRAN_APPENDAGE:
        return true;
...
}
```

Goes to removal code snippet:

```
    // Octopodes lose their extra ring slots (3--8) in forms that do not
    // have eight limbs.  Handled specially here because we do have to
    // distinguish between slots the same type.
    if (i >= EQ_RING_THREE && i <= EQ_RING_EIGHT
        **&& !(form_keeps_mutations(form) || form == TRAN_SPIDER))**
    {
        result.insert(eq);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the most correct and complete answer! I have played a few games with statue and lich octopodes and I can verify they kept all the rings.